# Using a different object mapper for a part of json

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

For our service input, we use an object mapper with certain configs to serialize it. We provide the same object mapper configs to our client in our client-lib and use the same to deserialize the input at our end.

Now we are adding another object to our input which is owned by a common team and has it's own object mapper config to correctly serialize it.

```
class MyAPIRequest {
    MyOtherOwnedClass1 obj1;
    MyOtherOwnedClass2 obj2;

    //New Shared class which is being added as part of input now: 
    CommonlyOwnedClass newObj;

}


class MyAPIRequestObjectMapperFactory() {
   static ObjectMapper newInstance(IonSystem ionSystem) {
        final ObjectMapper  objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();                 
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}

class CommonlyOwnedClassObjectMapperFactory() {
   static ObjectMapper newInstance(IonSystem ionSystem) {
        final ObjectMapper  objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();                 
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

How can I update my ObjectMapper to use a different ObjectMapper (provided by `CommonlyOwnedClassObjectMapperFactory`)  for newObj and continue to use existing object mapper (in `MyAPIRequestObjectMapperFactory`) for rest of objects in `MyAPIRequest` ?

Edit : 
I am using Jackson-2.8, but can upgrade to 2.9 if required

Comment: Which version of jackson are you using??

Comment: @chinoy I am using Jackson-2.8

Answer (score 0):

The setVisibility method is controlled by an protected configuration variable (_serializationConfig & _deserializationConfig in 2.8 and _configOverrides in 2.9). The method setVisibility is overloaded which takes an visibility checker to override internal configuration variable. You can use the overloaded version to set configuration for your mapper by getting the visibility checker from external mapper.

```
ObjectMapper yourObjectMapper = MyAPIRequestObjectMapperFactory.newInstance();
    ObjectMapper externalObjectMapper = CommonlyOwnedClassObjectMapperFactory.newInstance();
    yourObjectMapper.setVisibility(externalObjectMapper.getVisibilityChecker());
    //then set your visibility
```

Comment: I wan the visibility checker to be overloaded for objects of `CommonlyOwnedClass` and it's sub objects but not for other class/objects like  `MyOtherOwnedClass1` & `MyOtherOwnedClass2`